# Does the Scarlatti's 'Cortege' really sound like Gaudeamus Igitur?

Tags: history, analysis, melody

Every time I hear https://imslp.org/wiki/Keyboard_Sonata_in_E_major%2C_K.380_(Scarlatti%2C_Domenico), I think I'm hearing the melody for the third and fourth lines of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaudeamus_igitur. In particular, the Scarlatti comes to a cadence and then launches into a second melody which is the source of this earwormy moment. Does this make any sense in terms of musical history?

I suppose there are two questions here: (1) does it make any sense for Scarlatti to have been listening to university students, or (2) is there something about the structure of the two melodies that makes the resemblence?

Comment: You would be surprised as to how much of Bachs great discography was partially composed by the students he mentored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) does it make any sense for Scarlatti to have been listening to university students?

Of course.  Why wouldn't he?  (It's not clear, to the casual researcher at least, that university students in Italy would have been singing this melody in those days, however; Wikipedia says that the melody was first published in Leipzig a quarter century after Scarlatti's death.  It also says without citation that the melody was known before then, which is certainly likely.)

> (2) is there something about the structure of the two melodies that makes the resemblence?

This is easier to answer more definitively, and of course the answer is *yes.*  Both have the basic structure *sol-la-sol* with the rhythm *long-short-long* and slightly different embellishment.  In both cases, the embellishment begins with an irregular rhythm and ends with an even rhythm, which is common in stately or ceremonial music of the baroque and classical periods.

In the case of *Gaudeamus,* the first *sol* takes three beats (with the first actually realized as *mi-fa* in a dotted rhythm).  In the Scarlatti, the *sol* is repeated five times over two beats.   The *la* is in both cases one beat divided evenly in two; *Gaudeamus* has *la-fa* while the Scarlatti has *la-do.*  Finally, the last *sol* is simply *sol* in both cases, two beats for *Gaudeamus* and three for the Scarlatti.  In the case of the Scarlatti, there is an echo of the same figure in the tenor octave at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I’d say the similarity between these motives can be reduced to a motive falling from the fifth of the chord to the third, filling up the interval using a dotted note. Needlessly to say this is a very generic kind of motive and assuming any influence in any direction here would not be feasible. In fact while Scarlatti brings the motive on the tonic, Gaudeamus igitur has it on the subdominant and also progresses in a very different way.